# Delete appended upload box field jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make sure that when I click on the X button to delete an upload box, the entire upload box is deleted and not just the button section. Here is my code:

JS:

```
   function addFile(el) {
     if ($("#uploading tr").length < 6) {
       jQuery(el).parent().append('<a href="#" class="button" onclick="return removeFile(this)">x</a>');
       jQuery(el).remove();
       jQuery("#uploading").append('<tr><td><input type="file" name="images[]"></td><td><a href="#" class="button" onclick="return addFile(this)">+</a></td></tr>');
       return false;
     }
   }
```

HTML:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div style="overflow: hidden">
        <table class="adminformlist" id="uploading">
            <tr><td align="left">Upload Images(Maximum of 5 images):
                <input type="hidden" size="40" class="inputbox" value="" id="getyoutube" name="youtubevalue">
                <input type="hidden" size="40" class="inputbox" value="" id="getyoutubeurl" name="youtubevalueurl">
                </td>
                <td></td>       
            </tr>   
            <tr><td><input type="file" name="images[]"></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="button" onclick="return addFile(this)">+</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: @bipen this is for you

Comment: Where is the `removeFile()` function? It also is a little odd that you're using outdated `on*` event handlers when you can add unobtrusive event handlers using jQuery

Comment: Can you improvise your question,it is confusing what exactly your trying to do??

Comment: It is not my code, I am modifying a component. All I want to do is delete the entire upload box on click (The opposite of adding/appending an upload box). The removeFile() function is jQuery(el).remove();